# VS2015 brace match colors within a string

Tags: visual-studio-2015, background-color

In VS2015, when editing an Azure ARM template (JSON), there is a subtle background applied to matched braces within a string.  Using Photoshop I've been able to identify the color as rgb(244,244,244) #F4F4F4 as seen in the image below.

[image: in-string brace matching in VS2015]

This color is WAY to subtle for my eyes and I'd like to change it, but I can't work out which of the 79,428 color attributes to change in the VS Fonts & Colors options list.

Does anyone know which Fonts & Colors option controls this backgroun color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the setting needed is just `Brace Matching` and `Brace Matching (Rectangle)` - but for some editors (e.g. C#) it is sufficient to close the tab and re-open it to get the new colouring, while in the JSON case I needed to shut down Visual Studio altogether.

Leaving this here for posterity.